# "Failed to import the ActiveX control" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, com, visual-studio-2013, activex

I've been trying to upgrade an old COM control and associated WinForms project from VS2008 to VS2013. I've recreated the COM control from scratch in 2013 using a project type of `MFC COM Control` from the wizard. The control has been built successfully (creating a .ocx file) and has been registered using `regsvr32 xxx.ocx`.

I'm now trying to add this new COM control to a brand new (empty) WinForms project using .NET 3.5 in VS2013. I add the control to the Toolbox without any problem, but as soon as I drag the control onto the form, I get the following error:

`Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered.`

Two new references are added to the project, one being the control itself and the other being the control prefixed with `Ax`. The latter reference shows a warning icon.

If I then try to build the project, I get the following errors:

[image: Build Errors]

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer might not be useful to the asker of the question, but I just had the problem, and solved it. So I want to put it here for Other people that might have the same issue later.
So When I downloaded the latest adobe reader this happened(2015 version). So I download an older version, 
[Using this link](https://get.adobe.com/reader/download/?installer=Reader_11.0.10_English_for_Windows&standalone=1) (version 2011), and the problem was solved. 
Hope this helps someone out there.